# Combining items in game

Tags: java

In my game, a user will be able to combine items and if compatible will yield item a new item. Item IDs are saved as int.

I was wondering what the most efficient way to do this would be, while making sure that swapped order will always yield the same result, so the user could input the order:

```
item X + item Y = item Z
item Y + item X = item Z
```

I initially thought of doing something simple like a switch:

```
private int findItem(id1, id2)
{
     int newID = 0; 
     switch(id1)
     {
          case 1:
             if(id2.equals(4))
                 newID = 9;//Item 1 + Item 4 = Item 9
          break;
     }
  return newID
}
```

However, I'm not sure that using a switch is the most efficient (or tidy), and I'd have to create another case in the event that the function receives the item IDs in opposite order. I'd also have to have a case within a case to evaluate all of the things "id1" could combine with.

Is there a simple way to do this that won't span 1,000's of lines while staying efficient?

Comment: use `==` compare primitive types values

Comment: Use some clever mathematics to choose the ids, perform a simple addition and get the resulting item from a `Map<Integer, Item>`.

Comment: How many possible items are there?

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson a few right now, but I want to continue to add new items so it will grow over time and become potentially huge.

Comment: @haifzhan nice catch. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using a `Map<Set<Item>, Item>>` to store the recipes. Its key would be a set of needed items (possibly more than two), and its value the crafted item.

You could then check if a recipe exists with its `.containsKey(Set<Item>)` method and get the crafted result with its `.get(Set<Item>)` method.

Note that your items will have to override `Object.hashCode()` for this solution to work.

Here is a little code snippet in case it's not so clear : http://ideone.com/MbnsrC

Comment: This way, you could define the recipes in a separate file, and use it to populate the Map, instead of having it as part of the code.

Comment: Your provided code example really helped me understand the concept and I was able to adapt it and make it work! Is this solution foolproof for determining the recipes return item, or could there ever coincidentally be something that shares the same hash or a smiliar issue?

**Edit**: You responded to my previous comment, but I have since changed it to strings. Sorry for the confusion. I'm marking this as solved now.

Comment: hashcodes can't theoretically guarantee identity on large enough sets (like the infinite set of all possible strings) because of its int type, which only has so much unique values. In practice you'd have to be really unlucky to get two different items with the same hashcode unless the algorithm is poor. If you need to guarantee equality, equals() is what you need.